# Computed properties based on sideloaded relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So I am moving our app from ember-data 0.13 to ember-data 1.0 and I seem to be having trouble with 'sideloading' when I want to find all/multiple Records of a type and creating a computed property out of it.
I have a model like this:

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    someAttributes    : DS.attr('string'),
    rel       : DS.hasMany('rel'),

    important: function () {
        var rel = this.get('rel');
        return rel.filterProperty('reactionType', 'important');
    }.property('rel'),

    whatever: function () {
        var rel = this.get('rel');
        return rel.filterProperty('reactionType', 'whatever');
    }.property('rel')
})
```

And the JSON response from the server looks like this:

```
{events:
    [{ someAttributes: 'attr1', rels: [1, 2, 4]}, 
    {someAttributes: 'attr2', rels: [3]}],
 rels:
    [{ id: 1, reactionType: "whatever" },
    { id: 2, reactionType: "important" },
    { id: 3, reactionType: "important" },
    { id: 4, reactionType: "whatever"}]
 }
```

So first of all, is that JSON response correct? (Haven't seen an official example yet)
And second of all how can I get a computed property like this to work? It worked in ember-data 0.13. I also tried to move the computed property to the 'rel' model, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.
Anyway, hope that makes sense and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. For hasMany, you need to have plural: `rels: DS.hasMany('rel')` . And you need @each. JSON format is correct.

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    someAttributes    : DS.attr('string'),
    rels       : DS.hasMany('rel'),

    important: function () {
        var rel = this.get('rels.content');
        return rel.filterProperty('reactionType', 'important');
    }.property('rels.@each'),

    whatever: function () {
        var rel = this.get('rels.content');
        return rel.filterProperty('reactionType', 'whatever');
    }.property('rels.@each')
})
```

**Update**: modified this.get('rels') to this.get('rels.content')

Comment: whoop sorry I did have that, just mad an error. Thank you for the answer, I tried it with @each now, but it still doesn't work. There are a few other things I just thought about looking into a bit later today, but as of now it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you try this.get('rel.content').filterProperty('reactionType', 'important') ? rel.content gives you the array.

Comment: Aaahh, something really stupid: I still returned reaction_type rather than now reactionType. But it seems both, with and without .content it works. Sorry for that and thanks again for the help